# ASP.NET Response.Redirect Max URL Length

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I'm looking at creating a simple URL shortening service for our corporate intranet, and I'm curious if anyone knows if there's a maximum length for URLs returned by ASP.NET's Response.Redirect method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is 2083 (for GET is is 2048).  Other browsers have slightly different limits.  There is no limit defined in the standard.  Most folks seem to agree that something in the range of what IE permits is the functional limit.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the browser limits, just didn't know if ASP.NET had a restriction on what it could return.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum URL length for IE is 2083 Characters. Check [this](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) out for a complete list.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Probably just as important as ASP.NET's limit is that which the browser(s) set:

[What is the character limit on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url)

The url parameter for Response.Redirect() is of type `string` - considerably larger :-)