# Big long query string works fine on staging server, returns HTTP 406 on production server?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have a javascript event which is supposed to take me to another location:

```
onclick="window.location.href='index.php?get=[a big long 550-character string]'"
```

This works perfectly on apache running locally on my machine, but when I upload the script to my webhost this redirect returns HTTP 406 NOT ACCEPTABLE in IE and just a blank page in Firefox.

Is there a server configuration thing I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what actual URL is being processed on the server. I.e.: check if it is being truncated. I say this because certain platforms/configurations only allow URLs up to a certain number of characters. ***Usually*** anything upto 2048 is fine, but certain platforms may limit it to 256 characters.

This thread may be useful: [What is the character limit on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url)