# drawing a path on google static map

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I wrote this code in client side and sent to a server for a emailing purpose.in that email the image is appear as broken image I want to draw a path on google static map.here is the code I used.

```
<img src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:orange%7Cenc:'+polyline+'" />
```

polyline I created this way

```
 var polyline;
var points = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<googleRoute.getVertexCount(); i++)
{
    points[i] = new GLatLng(googleRoute.getVertex(i).lng(),googleRoute.getVertex(i).lat());
}
polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7);
```

when I used this code it will not appear the image.I wrote this code in client side and sent to a server for a emailing purpose.in that email the image is appear as broken image are there any wrong with my code?

Comment: Polylines only work on dynamic maps

Comment: @alex:this has a topic called encoded polyline http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/
I think polyline work for static map also

Comment: Ah, so you can. Cool! Well, how are you rendering the image? If it's not in javascript then you can't reference "polyline". Maybe post a little more code?

Comment: @alex:I wrote this code in client side and sent to a server for a emailing purpose.in that email the image is appear as broken image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when distance between two cities grows, the polyline variable will include lot of Glatlang values. so it causes to exceed the url character limit ([What is the character limit on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url)).
 we can't send long url that exceed the charcter limit using ajax request. that's why I got that broken image. 
As the solution I ignored intermediate Glatlang values by incrementing the for loop with skipping values. Therefore the polyline can be accepted for zoomed out maps.

Comment: I added extra characters as the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of points you can simply do:

```
$points = array('53.061969559518,-3.1661187796875', '52.647368106972,-2.6806604056641');
$pointsUrl = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($points); $i++) {
   $pointsUrl .= '%7C'.$points[$i];
}
echo '<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000ff%7Cweight:5'.$pointsUrl.'&size=270x256&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false" />';
```