# Getting InvalidURLError: ApplicationError: 1 in URLFetch

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidURLError: ApplicationError: 1
```

Checked my code, and logged some various things and the url's causing this error to appear look pretty normal. They are being quoted through urllib.quote and visiting them through a browser results in a normal result.

The error is happening with many URL's, not one. The URL points to an API service and is constructed within the app.

Btw,here's a link to the google.appengine.api.urlfetch source code: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py?r=56.

The docstrings say that the error should happen when: "InvalidURLError if the url was invalid." and "If the URL is an empty string or obviously invalid, we throw an urlfetch.InvalidURLError"

Just to make it simple for those who would like to test this:

```
url = 'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=REMOVEDKEY&maxwidth=400&urls=http%3A//V.interesting.As,http%3A//abcn.ws/z26G9a,http%3A//apne.ws/z37VyP,http%3A//bambuser.com/channel/baba-omer/broadcast/2348417,http%3A//bambuser.com/channel/baba-omer/broadcast/2348417,http%3A//bambuser.com/channel/baba-omer/broadcast/2348417,http%3A//bbc.in/xFx3rc,http%3A//bbc.in/zkkLJq,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/former-president-bush-to-speak-at-billings-fundraiser-in-may/article_f7ef425a-349c-56a9-a399-606b48033f35.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/former-president-bush-to-speak-at-billings-fundraiser-in-may/article_f7ef425a-349c-56a9-a399-606b48033f35.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/friday-forecast-calls-for-cloudy-windy-day-nighttime-snow-possible/article_d3eb3159-68b0-5559-8255-03fce56eaedd.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gallery-toy-run/collection_f5042a31-bfd4-5f63-a901-2a8c3e8fb26a.html%230,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gas-prices-continue-to-drop-in-billings/article_4e8fd07e-0e1e-5c0e-b551-4162b60c4b60.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gas-prices-continue-to-drop-in-billings/article_713a0c32-32c9-59f1-9aeb-67b8462bbe88.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gas-prices-continue-to-fall-in-billings-area/article_2bdebf4b-242c-569e-b414-f388a48f4a14.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gas-prices-dip-below-a-gallon-at-some-billings-stations/article_c7f4d373-dc2b-55c0-b457-10346c0274a6.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/gas-prices-keep-dropping-in-billings-area/article_3666cf9c-4552-5108-9d5c-de2bba12fa3f.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/government-and-politics/city-picks-st-vincent-as-care-provider-for-health-insurance/article_a899f885-15e1-5b98-b899-75acc01e8feb.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/government-and-politics/linder-settles-in-after-first-year-as-sheriff/article_55a9836e-2196-546d-80f0-48bdef717fa3.html,http%3A//billingsgazette.com/news/local/government-and-politics/new-council-members-city-judge-sworn-in/article_bb7ac948-1d45-579c-a057-1323fb2e643d.html'
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url)
```

Here's the traceback:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 263, in fetch return rpc.get_result()
    File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
    File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 359, in _get_fetch_result
    raise InvalidURLError(str(err))
    InvalidURLError: ApplicationError: 1

I wonder if it's something very simple that I'm missing from all of this. Would appreciate your comments and ideas. Thanks!

Comment: post the url that is invlid, you might have a problem with international chars.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I mean, if you could use a URL greater than 20148 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is too long, [there is a limit on the length of URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).

Comment: Thanks Shay, you know what the limit is?

Comment: THanks, according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url it's 2048