# Is it possible that if my current page's url is too long - I will have problems opening a link inside that page

Tags: javascript, html, browser, href

I have an iframe inside my webpage. the iframe's URL is very very long since it passes many parameters (let's forget for now that it should be shorter and more elegant).

Inside that iframe I have a simple link like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.internal.somegenericlink.com?p=1&d=2">link</a>
```

When I click the link - sometimes I do not see the new link (I get a 413 error) - and after I refresh the new page (with the new link) it does work.

this is an odd case and my question is:

**Is it possible that I can not see the new page because the iframe's URL is too long?**

I am trying to figure out whether the problem is on my side (url too long?!) or is this a problem with the new link that does not concern me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the character limit on URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for an URL to be too long. There is no standard, less than 2000 should be safe.

Usually, the error messages are pretty clear about URL:s being too long; 413 Entity Too Large is such an error.

More detail in [What is the character limit on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url)