# maxUrlLength maxQueryStringLength maxRequestPathLength

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

I have the following in the web.config file

```
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2097151" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

However, if the url is really long it throws a 404 error in fact if the string is over 2096 characters long.

Does anyone know a work around?

thanks

Comment: I think maximum url length is depended on Browsers. Please check this Stack overflow Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url.

Comment: Im not actually browsing to it, it's an ipad app that is posting json data to it

Comment: ok for all those people who will encounter this problem. in server 2012  go to "request filtering" "edit feature" then modify maximum url length and max query string bytes.

Answer (score 3):

ok for all those people who will encounter this problem.

In server 2012 go to your site -> "request filtering" -> "edit feature"

Then modify maximum url length and max query string bytes