# Creating Web Service in ASP.NET from existing API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, transactions

I am looking to create a web service from an existing API. The existing API is from a separate Windows program that allows the calculation of mileages between 2 more more locations. The API is in C#. There are also different types of calculations (Shortest Distance, Lowest-Cost, etc).

I am confused on how to create a RESTFUL web service that will allow multiple locations. Example in RESTFUL API tutorials show for an example api/books/1/To Kill A Mockingbird/ would get the record for a book. But how would this be for multiple locations? Would it be api/sd/Kansas City,MO/Chicago,IL/Miluwake,WI? How would it know if I'm looking to get the calculations of 2 vs. 10 locations? Could I program it to have 10 locations entered in the URL?

Comment: Doesn't seem like this fits with the 'transactions' tag.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use url segments to accept parameters. You could use a query string parameter with place names, say, semicolon-delimited, then split them out in your code.

```
/api/sd?cities=Kansas City,MO;Chicago,IL;Miluwake,WI
```

Then in your code just use `Request.QueryString["cities"].Split(';');`

Answer (score 1):

I think that as your route grows, you may run into other problems such as a url that is too long (there are limits to URL size, from what I understand -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051565/507025).  If you're going to have and API that can accept an endless number of parameters, I think you would want to do something like sending a JSON object with the request so the API controller can process it.

Additionally, a JSON object might be simpler to process, code wise.

Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226220/507025