# Can HTTP POST be limitless?

Tags: http, forms, post, limit

What is the specification for maximum data size one can send with HTTP POST method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633514/post-key-value-not-set-if-length-1000000-characters#56633638

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**EDIT (2019)** This answer is now pretty redundant but there is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless/55998160#55998160) with more relevant information.

It rather depends on the web server and web browser:

**Internet explorer**  All versions  2GB-1
**Mozilla Firefox**  All versions  2GB-1
**IIS**  1-5  2GB-1
**IIS**  6  4GB-1

Although IIS only support 200KB by default, the metabase needs amending to increase this.

http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/pa98.htm

The POST method itself does not have any limit on the size of data.

Comment: upvote for mentioning Metabase.XML and I have listed various ways to change the file upload size limit because it might be useful.

Comment: Entering following command in command prompt helps increase file upload size limit."cscript C:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/ASPMaxRequestEntityAllowed 10484880" (in bytes) reference:https://www.serverintellect.com/support/iis/uploaddownload-size-limits-iis6/

Comment: or find metabase.xml  in C:\windows\sytem32\inetserv\ path and edit but make sure Enable Direct metabase edit is enabled.reference:http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/file_upload_limits.asp

Comment: or In your web.config, add a line under your system.web <httpRuntime executionTimeout="54000" maxRequestLength="512000" /> http://weblogs.asp.net/mhawley/archive/2004/05/11/129824.aspx

Comment: For current (2019) web servers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless/55998160#55998160).

Answer (score 243):

Quite amazing how all answers talk about IIS, as if that were the only web server that mattered. Even back in 2010 when the question was asked, Apache had between [60%](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2010/12/01/december-2010-web-server-survey.html) and [70% of the market share](https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/web_server/ms/y). Anyway,

- The HTTP protocol does not specify a limit.
- The POST method allows sending far more data than the GET method, which is limited by the [URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) - about 2KB.
- The maximum [POST request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) size is configured on the HTTP server and typically ranges from
  **1MB to 2GB**
- The HTTP client (browser or other user agent) can have its own limitations. Therefore, the maximum POST body request size is `min(serverMaximumSize, clientMaximumSize)`.

Here are the POST body sizes for some of the more popular HTTP servers:

- Nginx ([largest web server market share](https://news.netcraft.com/archives/2019/04/22/april-2019-web-server-survey.html) as of April 2019) - default [1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476643/default-nginx-client-max-body-size/28476755#28476755), no practical maximum ([2**63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476643/default-nginx-client-max-body-size/28476755?noredirect=1#comment98741319_28476755))
- Apache - [maximum 2GB](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), no default documented
- IIS - [default 28.6MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#attributes) for the request length, 2048 bytes for the query string; maximum undocumented
- InfluxDB - [default ~25MB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/latest/administration/config/#max-body-size-25000000), maximum undocumented

Comment: Of those answers that mention a webserver two mention IIS and one mentions Apache. Anyway, have edited my answer to signpost towards yours which is more complete and up to date.

Comment: Thank you @DavidNeale! There should be a [badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327946/reward-someone-who-edited-their-answer-as-obsolete-to-point-to-mine) for that :) I'll try to keep this answer updated. Just added the maximum for nginx.

Comment: About this: "more data than the GET method, which is limited by the URL length - about 2KB." What about headers?
Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) it appears that headers allow for about 8-16KB .

Comment: @DanDascalescu note that nginx is misspelled (as ngix) in the answer body and thus wasn't found initially in my text search.

Comment: @BradHein: you have enough rep to edit answers; any reason why you didn't just do that?

Comment: Don't think we can say that GET method is limited by url length ~ 2kb, while GET request can have BODY which is actually seams limitless. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score 36):

There is no limit according to the HTTP protocol itself, but implementations will have a practical upper limit. I have sent data exceeding 4 GB using POST to Apache, but some servers did have a limit of 4 GB at the time.

Comment: Is 4GB still the maximum for Apache? I've [found it documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless/55998160#55998160) to be 2GB.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: I don't know, I haven't done this in a long time. Perhaps they started imposing an upper limit on the `LimitRequestBody` directive.

Answer (score 7):

POST allows for an arbitrary length of data to be sent to a server, but there are limitations based on timeouts/bandwidth etc.

I think basically, it's safer to assume that it's *not* okay to send lots of data.

Comment: Are there any rules of thumb for how much is getting dangerous for timeouts and such?

Answer (score 3):

Different IIS web servers can process different amounts of data in the 'header', according to this (now deleted) article; <s>http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/forms/what-is-the-limit-on-form/post-parameters.html</s>;

> Note that there is no limit on the
>   number of FORM elements you can pass
>   via POST, but only on the aggregate
>   size of all name/value pairs.    While
>   GET is limited to as low as 1024
>   characters, POST data is limited to 2
>   MB on IIS 4.0, and 128 KB on IIS 5.0.
>   Each name/value is limited to 1024
>   characters, as imposed by the SGML
>   spec. Of course this does not apply to
>   files uploaded using
>   enctype='multipart/form-data' ... I
>   have had no problems uploading files
>   in the 90 - 100 MB range using IIS
>   5.0, aside from having to increase the server.scriptTimeout value as well as
>   my patience!

Comment: Good edit @Matt - shows the importance of snipping out the salient facts rather than blindly linking

Answer (score 2):

HTTP may not have an upper limit, but webservers may have one. In ASP.NET there is a default accept-limit of 4 MB, but you (the developer/webmaster) can change that to be higher or lower.

Answer (score 2):

In an application I was developing I ran into what appeared to be a POST limit of about 2KB. It turned out to be that I was accidentally encoding the parameters into the URL instead of passing them in the body. So if you're running into a problem there, there is definitely a very small limit on the size of POST data you can send encoded into the URL.