# What is the practical limit of a textarea?

Tags: asp.net, iis, textarea

Using IE6+, what is the maximum amount of text you can POST with a `<textarea>` before something breaks?

Edit: The answer I'm hoping for is "there's no way you could actually type something meaningful and unmallicious into a textarea and crash Internet Explorer."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way POST data is sent there's no low-end limit to the number of characters you can send. There is an upper bound, of course. How much data are you talking about here?

The answer is **sneezing will cause IE to collapse, sneezing softly doubly so for IE6**

Comment: I'm hoping they could enter in 20 to 30 thousand characters without problem.

Comment: http://lipsum.com and try it quickly to see what happens. Save the source string on the server and test it against what's received. I don't have IE6 or I would whip you up a page.

Comment: I don't have it either. :/ (QA is trying to make me use javascript to limit the textarea so users don't crash their browser, which I think is silly)

Comment: see if IT can get you a VM with IE6 on an old copy of windows XP for testing

Comment: lol, that was fast. I should think 30k of text on an upload would be fine. Let us know if you ever find an upper bound below 4GB mkay?

Answer (score 1):

there's no way you could actually type something meaningful into a textarea and crash Internet Explorer..IE6+

Comment: You haven't used IE much have you?

Comment: Haha, personally I use firefox or chrome. But I am forced to test in IE, and from everything that could and will break IE, I have not broken it by using POST with too many characters in a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to have the users upload a file instead of copying and pasting 20 to 30 thousand characters into the textarea?

Comment: Yeah, if they are entering that many characters they are probably "doing it wrong", but I picked it as a worst case scenario.

Comment: think form submissions, like comments or the like. Yes, most of the time you won't have 30k characters, but you're thinking small fish. Think something like a forum. Or a blog engine. Those are still textareas.