# php uploading large files

Tags: php, upload, large-files

I'm stuck here with file uploading problem. I've searched for answers but found only "increasing post_max_size and upload_max_filesize" suggestion and that doesn't work for me. I can't get large files uploaded(approx. around 150mb+), the following are my php.ini settings and my environments

**php.ini**

```
 - max_input_time 300
 - max_execution_time 600
 - memory_limit 1024M
 - upload_max_filesize 1512M
 - post_max_size 2048M
```

**environments**

```
 - Webserver: XAMPP
 - PHPFramwork: CodeIgniter
```

I’ve also tried many other php.ini configurations. The file uploading class that I’ve built received posted file data from XmlHttpResponse request using xhr.send(file). I’ve debugged infos with firebug header is normal, post totally empty (normally it should be the file data, an in-read-able text), cookies are the ci_session cookies, and no xhr response text at all. I’ve write a script that will return some response no matter what, though.

I’m no experts in this, rather a newbie. This all information at hand that I can give to you guys. So, any ideas on what happen in this? I’m really stuck here can’t get this problem solve.

If there should be any info that I can look for and give it to you to get this problem solved do tell me so.

thx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to increase webserver's `TimeOut` Directive? Default value is 300 seconds. Check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) for documentation.

Comment: you could also add `set_time_limit(0);` to your controller method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead uploading with standard form try uploading with xhr object (as you said) but using file chunk method to send file to server, in this way theorically you should have not upload limits. Try this upload  jquery plugin that provides also php scripts:

http://code.google.com/p/ax-jquery-multiuploader/ REMOVE BECAUSE CANNOT MANTAIN

New link (free):
http://www.albanx.com/download.php?item_id=4

Documentation:
http://www.albanx.com/ajaxuploader/doc.php

Comment: This is a case where it would be good to have more information in in the answer.  The given link now appears to be dead.

Answer (score 5):

If you are uploading very large files such as a few GB, then there are actually browser side limitations. It appears that most modern browsers are [2GB - 4GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless). You should probably look into chunking (uploading parts of the file like a few MB at a time) your file uploads.

Comment: After hours of finding solutions, I've decided to use file chunking. thanks