# PHP upload file greater then 2gb

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I have a website where the admin has to upload HD quality movies. The size of movies are almost 2GB+

Will PHP or apache support a file upload of 2GB or greater?

What is the best way to do this?  Should I use ajax upload, swf upload(uploadify), or normal form submit upload?

I am using PHP 5.4

Comment: Are you sure a browser-based upload is the right way to go here? Uploading 2GB in a browser on a normal connection sounds *insane*. Especially considering you have to restart the entire upload if the connection breaks up for a moment. Have you considered alternatives like FTP?

Comment: For *sending* large files trough Apache https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ is very useful...

Comment: And your servers disk filesystem needs to support files larger than 2GB

Comment: Just found http://rightload.org/

Comment: Have you went through the previous threads about the subject? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590395/php-uploading-large-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864570/very-large-uploads-with-php

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am providing an admin tool to the client, he is not going to have access to FTP. Can I give any online control panel tool or something similar to that?

Comment: @powtac yay for rightload, works great... ntechi, there may be Java applets that allow for more stable uploads inside the browser, but something like FTP is usually really the way to go here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I saw you live in Tübingen... I live in Heidelberg...

Comment: @powtac oh, really? Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two PHP configuration options control the maximum upload size: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. Both can be set to, say, “10M” for 10 megabyte file sizes.

However, you also need to consider the time it takes to complete an upload. PHP scripts normally time-out after 30 seconds, but a 10MB file would take at least 3 minutes to upload on a healthy broadband connection (remember that upload speeds are typically five times slower than download speeds). In addition, manipulating or saving an uploaded image may also cause script time-outs. We therefore need to set PHP’s `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` to something like 300 (5 minutes specified in seconds).

These options can be set in your server’s php.ini configuration file so that they apply to all your applications. Alternatively, if you’re using Apache, you can configure the settings in your application’s .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

Finally, you can define the constraints within your PHP application:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

PHP also provides a `set_time_limit()` function so you don’t need to set `max_execution_time` directly.

Setting the options in your PHP code is possibly more practical, since you can extend the execution time and increase the file size when your application is expecting a large upload. Other forms would revert to the default 30-second time-out and 2MB limit.

Comment: What would you suggest to upload a file of 3GB? Its a dashboard, so I cant tell client to use filezilla for FTP

Comment: i didn't ask you to use FTP. Please read carefully

Comment: If I change the values for around 5G, 5G, 5000000, 5000000 will php accept these values?

Comment: Give a try & see. Theoretically it should work but practically i don't know because I haven't come across scenario like that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to increae the maximum file upload size in Apache's conf, as well as the post_max_size and upload_max_size directives in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

With files >=2GB you might reach some browsers limits. 
 Additionally, uploading 2GB might take some time (might exceed the timeout of the webserver). 
 
If your connection breaks, you have to re-upload the whole file again.

Comment: The server is likely fine, given that he doesn't have max keepalives set to something restrictive.