# Can't submit more than 15 values from multi-select dropdown

Tags: forms, jsp, post, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to submit a form which has fields such as country[dropdown], state[dropdown], hotel[multi-select dropdown]. I'm creating concatenated string of these selected values and submitting form POST via URL to another JSP target page.

I have encountered strange problem. I can select upto 15 values multi-select dropdown. Anything more than that request doesn't get submitted to target. Is there any limit associated with size or data in drop-down?

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: IMO there is no limit on multiselect. Try to add 14,15 and 16 values and check how the POST request is behaving. better add javascript function to add all selected values as array of params and submit the form.

Comment: @GustyWind I added JS function before submitting. Its alerting concatenated string, but fails to submit form! in next line of code

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a limit which would stop you from posting more than 15 values, there are some limits but you won't reach them with 15 select box values, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880777/1846192. There might also be a limit set at you web server.

It sounds more like a problem with the values you are posting, maybe have a good look at the posted data with a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). You'd have to post the post data here before I could be of any further help.