# Error while sending large (8mb) excel file using HttpWebRequest to servicestack service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, servicestack

I am trying to send large excel file to the  rest service ( using servicestack).

client and server(Servicestack service) applications are deployed on different server.

I am using following code at client side to upload the excel file ( 8 mb size)

taken from

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501608/Sending-Stream-to-ServiceStack

above code works fine when file to be uploaded is 2-3 MB.
it throws the error when file size is large about 8MB.
while debugging it gives me following error

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at Myproject.Web.Controllers
                  .Employer.FileUploadController
                  .Upload(FileUploadViewModel fileUploadViewModel
        ,HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload
        ,String DataFileType
        ,String UploadedFrom) 
    in d:\MyProject\projNewArch\Controllers\Employer\FileUploadController.cs:line 262
  InnerException:
```

i have tried changing the setting values which can be seen as connected.

What might be the issue? Please help

**Update 1: i have IIS 8.5 at server so i think the file size (8mb) might not be the issue. Do i still need to add the some setting in web.config to allow sending  big size file  over POST**

**UPDATE 2 :  Found the solution.
Adding maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength does the trick. Please check the link provided by Smartdev in comments section**

Comment: This link might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/is-http-post-limitless

Comment: ` (500) Internal Server Error` you need to look at the *server* traces, and debug the *server*.

Comment: @ulric I have updated the qustion . do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: This error is not triggered by your application. This is triggered by the 'remote server'. You should check it and if you have access to it, most probably you need to increase the `maxRequestLength` there. Check this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded.

Comment: @amol - tbh, I am a little out of my depth when it comes to the technical intricacies of IIS. Hopefully someone else will be able to provide a precise answer for you.

Comment: @ulric .thanks you very much for help

Comment: @SmartDev : OK .will try that

Comment: adding  maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength does the trick. Please check the link provided by smartdev

Answer (score 1):

You still need to edit your web.config file. It should look like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" /> 
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This will allow you to upload up to 10MB