# How to set large Request Body for fetch API call

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a `fetch` `POST` that is sending a large JSON object:

```js
const body = JSON.stringify(largeItem); // 80MB

const request = new Request(uri, {
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body
});

const response = await fetch(request);
```

This results in an error:

> `source-file.ts:72 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

When I view this request in dev tools it looks incomplete - no request body and most of the request headers are missing. In addition it errors without a status code, instead the status is:

> `(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Lots of other `GET` and `POST` requests to the same resource with the same credentials work fine. This code works fine with a smaller `body`.

How do I `POST` a request with a large (in this case 80MB) JSON body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is related to `http` or the `web server` (or I guess the browser) Limits

Please read this answer to know what I'm talking about

[Can HTTP POST be limitless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless#:~:text=The%20POST%20method%20allows%20sending,the%20URL%20length%20%2D%20about%202KB.&text=The%20HTTP%20client%20(browser%20or,min(serverMaximumSize%2C%20clientMaximumSize)%20).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, this was the problem. I expected the server to return a `405` or something like that for requests that are too large, but instead it just rejects the connection entirely.