# In a post method, what is the limit size of a json in the request body?

Tags: json, rest, httprequest

I know that there is a limit to the size of a **json** when sending in the request body but I did not find anything concrete.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless and https://serverfault.com/questions/151090/is-there-a-maximum-size-for-content-of-an-http-post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is similar to other data formats like XML - if you need to transmit more data, you just send more data. There's no inherent size limitation to the overall JSON request itself. Any limitation would be set by the server parsing the JSON request. (For instance, ASP.NET has the "MaxJsonLength" property of the serializer.)