# POST request is not working for large amount of data

Tags: python, html, post

I want to upload a file that is containing of more than 10,000 files. After taking input by using html file type input, it crashed. URL is also not working. Is post request not compatible with large amount of data?

Comment: It depends on server configuration. There's a maximum size. Take a look on [Can HTTP POST be limitless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2880722/10824407).

Comment: Server issue, client issue, how could we possible answer without seeing the code or any kind of specifications of the setup?