# How to send large chunks of data with fetch HTTP Post in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, http, fetch

I've been trying to send some data in React Native with `HTTP fetch`, but I can't send fairly large chunks of data. It stops sending from about 2200 characters of text.

```
export const postServerData = (myURL, myJSONData, callback) => {
  fetch(myURL, {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(myJSONData),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(myReturnedData => {
      callback(myReturnedData);
  })
  .catch(error => {
  });
};
```

From a few articles, data cap is quite fairly large :

[Can HTTP POST be limitless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless/55998160#55998160)

> The maximum POST request body size is configured on the HTTP server and typically ranges from
> 1MB to 2GB

How can I send larger chunks in React Native *(Android)*?

Comment: How do you know *It stops sending from about 2200 characters of text* ?

Comment: It sends with smaller chunks. I can do a _console.log_ of the payload on the server side. Nothing shows with large chunks.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a server problem ? Did you try to POST something big from another client ?

Comment: t works from the browser / Website. It doesn't from React Native