# C# ASP.NET Core MVC website sometimes receives NULL instead of POSTED value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

I've a C# ASP.NET Core MVC website. I'm running it in Visual Studio. I'm posting to a controller action that takes parameter string[] identifiers. The HTML form element is a textarea that has values like:

```
one
two
three
```

This works fine, and `identifiers` is properly populated with 3 entries.

If the textarea instead has 37,000+ lines (1.4 MB when saved to disk as a text file), then the controller sees `identifiers` as NULL.

In my `Startup.cs` I've used (and have also used with just the defaults):

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(o =>
{
    o.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(o =>
{
    o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});

services.Configure<FormOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    o.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

And my `web.config` (I'm running this from Visual Studio, and `web.config` is set to "Copy Always") contains:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</configuration>
```

There are no errors or warnings in the Windows Event Viewer, so I suspect it's an issue in code?

Assuming the issue is related to max POST size, where have I gone wrong?

**Update**
The data is posted with jQuery ajax, with no contentType specified. I think the default is:
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
which likely limits the request to 2k. Though explicitly setting a contentType doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can HTTP POST be limitless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880722/can-http-post-be-limitless)

Comment: The answers in that thread should give you some ideas on things to check. Since we don't have access to your environment, it's up to you to research and figure out what is imposing the limitation.

Comment: @devlincarnate FormOptions.ValueLengthLimit defaults to nearly 30 MB, but that should be far more than I need anyway.

Comment: What is the Response code? Check dev tools in your browser (F12).

Comment: @mxmissile The response code will be an exception because the controller's parameter is receiving a list as NULL instead of having values. The controller attempts to iterate through the list (which is a NULL object)

Comment: Inspect the Request object in your action method with your debugger. Might have some hints.

Comment: @mxmissile When I have the 37,000+ rows in the textarea Chrome's "Payload" tab shows nothing at all. But when there are about ~10,000 records it properly shows an array with the expected number of elements.

Comment: Try changing your `<TextArea>` `maxlength` to something greater than 524288. That is default. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-textareamaxlength-attribute/

Comment: @mxmissile I didn't know textarea had a maxlength. My value is 1.3 million characters. I set the maxlength to 2000000 (2 million), but alas the same bug persists. A few thousand records works, not sure what is happening. I might have to install Wireshark or similar to see what is actually being posted I suppose.

Comment: I was afraid of that, the fact that Chrome's Payload shows nothing AND you are not actually getting a payload leads me to believe this is a browser or jquery issue.

Comment: @mxmissile I was thinking the same. I've WireShark installed now, I'll soon know if the value is being posted or not. At least that'll narrow down where the issue is. It's being posted with jQuery's ajax, I'm thinking it might be the issue.

Comment: Could you share your html code and posted with jQuery ajax code ?So that we can reproduce your problem. If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I had to add the following to my controller:

```
[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```

I had thought the code below would do the same thing, but it does not solve the problem. Note that `services` is an instance of IServiceCollection and is used in my Startup.cs (where we also inject our settings, database connection, set session details, etc).

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```