# What is the maximum length of referer?

Tags: http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Hello, I want to log referer into my database , I want to know what the maximum length is for referer ?

Comment: The same as max length of url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url

Comment: Referrer is a header in the HTTP request. While the URL length maximum is a recommendation there's no strict limit, so someone could send you a referrer header that is much longer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values for more discussion on the length of headers, although these are also not limited by spec so likely they are limited by your server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `referer` is a URL, so you can refer to [this answer about maximum URL lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url). URLs will almost certainly be no more than 2083 characters in length, as this is the [maximum supported by some versions of IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427), and it looks like [Google doesn't index anything over 1855 characters](http://www.seomofo.com/experiments/title-and-h1-of-this-post-but-for-the-sake-of-keyword-prominence-stuffing-im-going-to-mention-it-again-using-various-synonyms-stemmed-variations-and-of-coursea-big-fat-prominent-font-size-heres-the-stumper-that-stumped-me-what-is-the-max-number-of-chars-in-a-url-that-google-is-willing-to-crawl-and-index-for-whatever-reason-i-thought-i-had-read-somewhere-that-googles-limit-on-urls-was-255-characters-but-that-turned-out-to-be-wrong-so-maybe-i-just-made-that-number-up-the-best-answer-i-could-find-was-this-quote-from-googles-webmaster-trends-analyst-john-mueller-we-can-certainly-crawl-and-index-urls-over-1000-characters-long-but-that-doesnt-mean-that-its-a-good-practice-the-setup-for-this-experiment-is-going-to-be-pretty-simple-im-going-to-edit-the-permalink-of-this-post-to-be-really-really-long-then-im-going-to-see-if-google-indexes-it-i-might-even-see-if-yahoo-and-bing-index-iteven-though-no-one-really-cares-what-those-assholes-are-doing-url-character-limits-unrelated-to-google-the-question-now-is-how-many-characters-should-i-make-the-url-of-this-post-there-are-a-couple-of-sources-ill-reference-to-help-me-make-this-decision-the-first-is-this-quote-from-the-microsoft-support-pages-microsoft-internet-explorer-has-a-maximum-uniform-resource-locator-url-length-of-2083-characters-internet-explorer-also-has-a-maximum-path-length-of-2048-characters-this-limit-applies-to-both-post-request-and-get-request-urls-the-second-source-ill-cite-is-the-http-11-protocol-which-says-the-http-protocol-does-not-place-any-a-priori-limit-on-the-length-of-a-uri-servers-must-be-able-to-handle-the-uri-of-any-resource-they-serve-and-should-be-able-to-handle-uris-of-unbounded-length-if-they-provide-get-based-forms-that-could-generate-such-uris-a-server-should-return-414-request-uri-too-long-status-if-a-uri-is-longer.html).

So if you're storing as a `CHAR` then go for 2083 to be safe, and if you're storing as a `VARCHAR` then it really doesn't matter since any string over 255 characters takes 2 bytes to store its length so go for something high like 3000.