# XMLHttpRequest: implementing interceptor issue

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, interceptor

I am trying to implement an interceptor following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446856/3023947) to be able to add an authentication header before sending an http request by *monkey patching* the `XMLHttpRequest#open` function.

My code is shown below (`storage` is just a service that holds the access token):

```js
// auth-interceptor.js
module.exports = ({ storage }) => {
  const oldXHROpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = () => {
    const res = oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);

    const accessToken = storage.get();

    if (accessToken) {
      this.setRequestHeader('Authentication', accessToken);
    }

    return res;
  };
};
```

```js
// auth-interceptor.spec.js
describe('auth interceptor', () => {
  let fakeTokenStorage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    fakeTokenStorage = { get: () => 'xxxx-access-token-xxxx' };
    authInterceptor({ storage: fakeTokenStorage });
  });

  it('should include authentication header', () => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://base_url/api/check');
    // check if header exists
  });
});
```

But when `.open()` gets called I get the following error:

> **InvalidStateError: The object is in an invalid state.**

```
  3 |
  4 |   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = () => {
> 5 |     const res = oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
    |                            ^
  6 |
  7 |     const accessToken = storage.get();
  8 |
```

It seems that the `oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments)` call is going wrong... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Got it solved.

**Replaced:**

```js
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = () => { }
```

**For:**

```js
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() { }
```

For further information: [Why do arrow functions not have the arguments array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41731854/3023947)