# Does (a high) maxHttpHeaderSize have disadvantages?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat7

Setting maxHttpHeaderSize to high/ infinity value causes any issue?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values

Comment: I know that there is no limit from HTTP protocol, but I am interested in finding why there are limits for each server and what is disadvantage if we open it up or make it infinite. Thanks

Comment: An attacker could send you a request with a huge header and cause memory problems for your server. I would rather wonder what you would *gain* by making it infinite. What's the point?