# Reading Content headers being cut off by android?

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I am making a call to an API, the API returns fine in C# for another application but in Android for our APP it is cutting off after the 5534 character, for smaller sets of data it returns fine but after this it gets cutt off.. the string looks something like this:

`response.getFirstHeader("X-JSON").getValue()` is returning this

```
[{"Customer":"","Name":"Fred","MI":"","ContactType":"Person","Id":8909,"IsDeleted":false,"TotalClients":0},...."MANY MORE HERE"...
 ...{"Customer":"","Name":"Test Name","MI":"B","ContactType":"Person","Id"
```

I get all the lines fine up to the last one as you can see it cutts off by "Id". When I try with a smaller set, by calling the API to a smaller account, its fine.. it never gets cutt off and I obtain the expected results, on the other hand for this big account with a lot of data it just doesnt get everything..

Any idea of what could be the issue?

Related Code below:

```
        DefaultHttpClient client = HttpSingleton.getThreadSafeClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
        get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        get.abort();
        printHeaders(response);             
        responseString = response.getFirstHeader("X-JSON").getValue();
```

Comment: why do you return data in a header ?

Comment: i dont know this is an external API, we dont have control of how it is being returned.

Comment: maybe it is passed in the body too, i am going to see what the body returns..

Comment: did you try using httpurlconnection rather than httpclient? may be the httpclient library reads only so much of a header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing data as an HTTP header? There is a limit on the size of data you can pass in an HTTP header.. See this:

[Maximum on http header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values)

Why not pass data in response body as usually?

Comment: I am actually Getting data from the server, I am trying to get it from a given API, we know for sure the API works and it passes all the data because we use it for the IPhone, but i am not sure why android is cutting it off, we just started working on the Android App and its kind of new for us.

Comment: Agree with @Oscar, it's not standard to send what's arguably the content of the request in the headers.

Comment: You get data from the server when the max header size in your application server is not reached. 
But once that value is overcome, the header is truncated and unexpected behavior arise... 
Http headers are there to carry information about the client browser, the requested page, the server and more, and request payload is there to represent the real request data. Send the data in the request body instead that in HTTP headers and your problem will be solved.