# Error 500: Premature end of script headers

Tags: php, cgi

I get a "Premature end of script headers: contactform.cgi" error message when running the below script.  What frustrates me is that I ran this as a .php on another server and it worked.  However, I had to change servers and they only support CGI PHP.  However, it doesn't work.  I don't think the code is wrong, but take a look just in case.

I've read around and some have said it's a permissions issue.  Could this be the case for me?

I know that the "display_errors" and "error_reporting" statements will display errors in the error log, but if I don't have access to the server, how can I check the logs?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

//Email this form to me
$email_to = "myemail@site.com";

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "Oops... something's wrong. ";
    echo "Fix the error(s) below:<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    die();
}


// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('There appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}


$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$subject = $_POST['subject']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}


$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

//Email Subject (put here to include subject from form)
$email_subject = "SUBJECT | ".clean_string($subject)."";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

<?php
header("Location: thankyou.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: You have to manually output headers with cgi? Try print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";

Comment: is the print statement you have different than the print statement I use on line 5 of my script?

Comment: `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` -- isn't that Perl, not PHP?

Comment: woops, I think you're right.  Removed it.

Comment: I tried all of the above but found out it was a missing windows compiler. Downloading and installing this fixed the issue. To see if this is your problem, try to run PHP from command line. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397073/

Comment: For those of you that still get this error but are not in a similar situation, keep reading the other answers; the one that helps you might just be in there.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**It was a file permission issue.**

All files on my website were set to a permission level of '644.'  Once I changed the permission level to 705 ([`chmod 705`](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)) everything worked. Note that I changed it to 705, but 755 will also work. I also changed the folder it was in to 701 (to hide it, but still be executable by the server).

<sub>*Aside:* I still don't understand why my .PHP file worked on the other server when it was probably set to 644??  How could Apache execute the script without world permission??  Does Apache not need world permission??  Just a few questions I still have...</sub>

Comment: I'm speculating here, but it's possible that your host (at least at one point) used ```phpsuexec```, which runs as _you_. From bluehost's help docs: **"Using phpsuexec, php runs under your own username on the server. This removes the necessity to make files and folders world writable. Instead you can just use 755 for folders (the default) and 644 for files"**

Comment: I used 711 for the directory and it's contents successfully.

Comment: This worked for me. However I have to ensure that the 755 change was just made to "folders" and not files (that happened by mistake btw...using Filezilla).

Answer (score 9):

The "Premature end of script headers" error message is probably the most loathed and common error message you'll find.
What the error actually means, is that the script stopped for whatever reason before it returned any output to the web server.
A common cause of this for script writers is to fail to set a content type before printing output code. In Perl for example, before printing any HTML it is necessary to tell the Perl script to set the content type to text/html, this is done by sending a header, like so:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
```

(source; http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_Common_Web_dev_error_messages_and_what_they_mean.php#premature

Comment: I do that on line 5 of my script.  Should I be placing that somewhere else?

Comment: It's the first statement under the php tag, so it looks like it is already in the right place, correct?

Comment: Then, try to remove the space line on line 2. Is there something in the Apache error.log?

Comment: Just removed the space.  Didn't work.  I don't have direct access to the server so I can't check the error log.  Is there some other way of checking the log besides direct access??

Comment: Not really, I suggest you ask your systems administrator for help. You could try temporary deleting large parts of the file and see if something changes.

Comment: Get rid of everything before `<?php`. PHP doesn't need `#!` line, that's another perl-ism.

Comment: @Barmar That actually is needed.  It ends with /php and not /perl, thus it applies to php.  I know its necessary because it was a specific requirement from the webmaster for this particular server.

Comment: I have the same issue and this is not working for me.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this problem today, but unfortunately none of the suggestions here helped. The only problem was that I didn't see ANY errors.. I literally had to do an `strace -p <process_id>` on the Apache thread to spot the headers being written and Apache crashing on the next line; Somewhere in my PHP code I was setting a header with over 12KB of data.

The lesson here is that in some cases, Apache crashing with a `HTTP error 500 - Premature end of script`-failure can be the result of having too long or overflowing HTTP headers.

**Debug your headers for length if you have this same problems because most (if not all) web servers have HTTP header limits.**

PS: [This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623061/286238) has some info on header sizes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This was my issue in our laravel application. There was a bug causing one of our custom headers to output far too much content in certain cases

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! This saved me after hours of debugging (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77586580/1142970). Wish I could give more upvotes :-)

Answer (score 3):

Check your line endings!  If you see an error about the file not being found, followed by this "premature of end headers" error in your Apache log - it may be that you have Windows line endings in your script in instead of Unix style.  I ran into that problem / solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is to do with file permissions and it happens on systems that have the suphp(usually cpanel/whost servers) installed.

**Removing the write permission** from anyone else but the owner(644|600) for the php files will fix the issue. That is how i got it fixed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was seeing `Directory "/data/www/USER/public_html" is writeable by group` above the error - this was exactly the right fix - `chmod 750` on public_html dir.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a cache directory that wasn't so big, only 17MB but duo to the file structure it took forever to be accessed by the website and was producing that error after max_execution_time was reached.

I renamed the directory to cache-BK and created a new cache directory with the same permissions and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this, I had to change permissions for whole directory to 755 (777 did not work for me), and changed file owners for whole directory

```
chmod -R 755 public_html
chown -R nobody:nobody public_html
```

nobody is user that runs php in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Error can be caused by various issues. for more info check suexec or fcgi logs.
For example if suexec has wrong user and permssion it can cause the error to occur
to solve try

```
chgrp WEBGROUP /usr/local/apache2/bin/suexec
chmod 4750 /usr/local/apache2/bin/suexec
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to change

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

u forgot to add proper content-type header in the response which is a must have http header when hosting on apache2

use

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (referencing a PHP file in the top folder of a Wordpress plugin) I had to change the permissions on that folder. My test environment was fine, but when deployed the folder had 775. I changed it to 755 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After many diff's, this was what was missing from the `httpd.conf` file on the server in question:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Solved the issue.

Comment: Caveat: This appears to be a niche Apache configuration, and probably under Ubuntu as well. I've never seen this directive used or needed.

Comment: It was an older version of apache(2.2.22)/php(5.3.8)/openssl that was compiled from source tarballs on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5

Comment: I think this way, you are just jusing mod_php?

Comment: Linked/compiled in on older systems when you couldn't get decently current releases via the package managers. During that time I compiled apache/php/openssl/zlib on every server. Don't need to do that anymore since there are many distros that keep up well.