# msvcr110.dll is missing from computer error while installing PHP

Tags: php, dll

I am trying to install PHP(5.5).
I extracted the zip file in `C:\php` folder. And I also set the 'Path' system variable to `C:\php`. But when I open command prompt and type `php` I get error saying:

> The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your
> computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I checked for this dll in `C:\Windows\System32` directory and I could locate the file there.
How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 88):

You need to install the Visual C++ libraries: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

As mentioned by Stuart McLaughlin, make sure you get the x86 version even if you use a 64-bits OS because PHP needs some 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Make sure you install the x86 version, even if running a 64-bit OS.  PHP uses some of the 32-bit libraries.

Comment: Thanks so much! Tried many other things but this is what got it working for me

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works. I tried many ways to resolve this error but it didn't.

Answer (score 41):

***Since link to this question shows up on very top of returned results when you search for "php MSVCR110.dll" (not to mention it got 100k+ views and growing), here're some additional notes that you may find handy in your quest to solve MSVCR110.dll mistery...***

***The approach described in the answer is valid not only for MSVCR110.dll case but also applies when you are looking for other versions, like newer `MSVCR71.dll` and I updated the answer to include VC15 even it's beyond  scope of the original question.***

---

On http://windows.php.net/ you can read:

> **VC9, VC11 and VC15**
>
> More recent versions of PHP are built with VC9, VC11 or VC15
> (Visual Studio 2008, 2012 or 2015 compiler respectively) and include
> improvements in performance and stability.
>
> The **VC9** builds require you to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for
> Visual Studio **2008** SP1 x86 or x64 installed.
>
> The **VC11** builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for
> Visual Studio **2012** x86 or x64 installed.
>
> The **VC15** builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for
> Visual Studio **2015** x86 or x64 installed.

This is quite crucial as you not only need to get Visual C++ Redistributable installed but you also need the **right version** of it, and which one is right and correct, depends on what PHP build you are actually going to use. Pay attention to what version of PHP for Windows you are fetching, especially pay attention to this "VCxx" suffix, because if you install PHP that requires VC9 while having redistributables  VC11 installed it is not going to work as run-time dependency is simply not fulfilled. Contrary to what some may think, you need **exactly** the version required, as newer (higher) releases does **NOT** cover older (lower) versions. so i.e. VC11 is not providing VC9 compatibility. Also VC15 is neither fulfilling VC11 nor VC9 dependency. It is just VC15 and **NOTHING ELSE**. Deal with it :)

For example,  archive name `php-5.6.4-nts-Win32-VC11-x86` tells us the following

[image]

1. it provides PHP v5.6.4,
2. PHP build is **N**on-**T**hread **S**afe (**nts**),
3. it provides binaries for Windows (**Win32**),
4. to run, Visual Studio 2012 redistributable (**VC11**) is required,
5. binaries are 32-bit (**x86**),

Most searches I did lead to **VC9** of redistributables, so in case of constant failures to make thing works, if possible, try installing different PHP build, to see if you by any chance do not face mismatching versions.

---

**Download links**

**Note that you are using 32-bit version of PHP, so you need 32-bit redistributable (x86) even if your version of Windows is 64-bit!**

- VC9: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2008: [x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582) or [x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)
- VC11: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012: [x86 or x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)
- VC15: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015: [x86 or x64](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)
- VC17: Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017: [x86 or x64](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Great explanation for PHP and Vsual C++ Redistribution. It helps me a lot.

Comment: as i observed: you will have to install the x86 version of the VC* even if you are on a x64 system
(with win 10 + php VC11)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I have VS2017 and choosing VC15 worked perfectly.  On a side note, I don't know why this installation has to be complicated.  Feels like piecing a frankenstein together.

Comment: php 5.6 has a experimental 64 bit version. When using that one as a CLI, make sure to install the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 7):

I am on a 64 bit system, and I only got this to work after installing both the 32 and 64 bit versions of the redistributable.  I did not try the 64 bit version by itself due to the other posters' warnings about using the 32 bit version (and am too lazy to uninstall the 32 bit version now that I have it working), so I don't know if the 32 bit version is needed or not in cases like mine.

Comment: This is my case too! Happened to me on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed PHP in IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 using the Web Platform Installer. It did not work out of the box. I had to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for VS 2012 Update 4 (32bit) as found here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 .

Comment: Resolved my issue. I was also getting the same subject line msvcr110.dll error when I tried to do php-cgi -v on command prompt or trying to access sample php page on localhost following instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779246/run-a-php-app-using-tomcat . My Env: Window Server 2008 Standard, PHP5.6.4, Sample PHP on Tomcat8. Also detailed instructions given in PHP documentation @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the MSVCR110.dll. Which I corrected. I could run php from the command line but not the web server. Then I clicked on php-cgi.exe and it gave me the answer. The php5.dll was missing (I downloaded the wrong copy). So for my 2012 IIS box I re-installed using php's x86 non thread safe zip.

Answer (score 0):

To identify which x86/x64 version of VC is needed:

Go to IIS Manager > Handler Mappings > right click then Edit *.php path.
In the "Executable (optional)" field note in which version of Program Files is the php-cgi.exe installed.

Answer (score 0):

One Line Answare for, Windows10 | XAMPP - Download [php-5.6.40-Win32-VC11-x86.zip](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.6.40-Win32-VC11-x86.zip)