# Strato / Php / Premature end of script headers

Tags: php

I´m running into the the error message:

> "Premature end of script headers"

I´m hosting my files at Strato, which means i´m not able to change the ini settings. The error don´t appears every time. I even don´t know, where the problem starts. Is there a way to check, where the problem starts and put it into a logfile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 500: Premature end of script headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583341/error-500-premature-end-of-script-headers)

Comment: I tried to change the CHMOD to 755 on the files but without any luck. The error still appears. The funny thing is that the error appears everye 3-4 hours for around 5-10 mintues. Does anyone have another idea?