# Specific PHP request fails mysteriously with 500 after seemingly innocuous change

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, amazon-ec2, vite

I have a PHP 8.2.7/laravel 10/inertia/vite/typescript/react app running on EC2. After a recent change to a .tsx file, *one particular* page route has started failing with a 500 response. The error does not appear in any laravel logs, only in Apache logs. The error does not reproduce in my local windows environment running on Xampp.

## The change

The change that "caused" the problem (in the sense that toggling the change makes the problem appear/disappear) was adding a single component import to a .tsx file:

```
import NewComponent from "...";
...
// When this is false vite optimizes away the import and the error does not occur.
// When this is true the error does occur
{false && <NewComponent ... />}
...
```

## The broken route

The route in my app that breaks is a simple inertia route that renders a page. The route is behind the standard web+auth+verified middleware stack:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function view() {
        return Inertia::render('MyPage');
    }
}
```

## The symptom

When the route is requested, from the browser (by pasting in the URL), I get a 500 response, with no content and `Content-Length: 0`. I also get a `Server` header showing `Apache/2.4.56 (Amazon Linux)`. All other routes (AJAX and pages) in the application work without issue. There are no TypeScript or Vite build errors.

The only evidence of the error I see server-side is entries like this in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:08.243216 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782568] [client 172.31.53.240:42570] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:08.243267 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782568] [client 172.31.53.240:42570] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:08.243273 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782568] (22)Invalid argument: [client 172.31.53.240:42570] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:49.615537 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782580] [client 172.31.53.240:40022] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:49.615578 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782580] [client 172.31.53.240:40022] AH01070: Error parsing script headers
[Fri Dec 01 15:21:49.615584 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1782534:tid 1782580] (22)Invalid argument: [client 172.31.53.240:40022] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

A google search suggests that this is indicative of PHP terminating unexpectedly.

## Debugging

### index.php

To try to find out where the request was terminating, I added log statements to `index.php`:

```
$time = time();
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$log = function($m) use ($time, $url) {
    $line = $time . ' ' . $url . ' ' . $m . PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/storage/logs/debug.log', $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
};
$_REQUEST['mylog'] = $log; // allow use from other files

register_shutdown_function(function () {
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('SHUTDOWN');
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('SHUTDOWN LAST ERROR ' . json_encode(error_get_last()));
});

$log('MADE KERNEL');

$r1 = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
);
$log('HANDLED REQUEST');
$response =$r1->send();
$log('SENT REQUEST');

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

$log('TERMINATED REQUEST');
```

From this I can see that most requests go through all logs starting with `MADE KERNEL` and ending with `SHUTDOWN LAST ERROR null`. *However, the particular bad path is missing the `SENT REQUEST` and `TERMINATED REQUEST` logs* (it still has the shutdown logs).

Going deeper, I then made local edits to `/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`:

```
public function sendContent(): static
{
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('ABOUT TO SEND CONTENT ' . mb_strlen($this->content));
    echo $this->content;
    //echo 'hello, world';
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('... CONTENT SENT!');

    return $this;
}

public function send(): static
{
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('IN RESPONSE->SEND');
    $this->sendHeaders();
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('SENT HEADERS');
    $this->sendContent();
    $_REQUEST['mylog']('SENT CONTENT');

    ...
}
```

What I learned from this is that *bad requests log up through `ABOUT TO SEND CONTENT` and then skip straight to the shutdown logs*. I've tried logging the content itself and it is a normal HTML payload as I would expect.

I've also tried commenting out `echo $this->content;` in favor of `echo 'hello, world'`. In this case the behavior is even more bizarre: now every other request returns `hello, world` as expected, and the bad request now emits all the normal log statements. However, *the bad request still returns with the same 500 response!*.

### php-fpm

I looked in the `php-fpm` logs; in `/var/log/php-fpm/` I have both `error.log` and `www-error.log`. `error.log` has no recent entries; one from several days ago says `WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (50), consider raising it`. `www-error.log` was empty. When I (temporarily) edited `index.php` to be syntactically invalid, I can see parse errors appearing in that file. However, when there are no syntax errors the bad requests hits a 500 and nothing is emitted to either file.

### UPDATE! Link header size

I suspect the problem is caused by Laravel sending `Link` header which is too large for what apache allows. Adding one additional react module dependency caused this Link header to grow beyond a certain threshold. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42141389/1142970) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23844761/1142970) seem relevant. Still searching for a fix.

**Any ideas on what this might be or where to debug next?** Thanks!

Comment: `$_REQUEST['mylog']('SHUTDOWN')` is wrong. Or your `$_REQUEST['mylog']` is function name?

Comment: @Justinas I stored an anonymous logging function in `$_REQUEST['mylog']`; see the line where I do `$_REQUEST['mylog'] = $log; // allow use from other files`.

Comment: So ... laravel in config/logging.php has an 'emergency', I believe. This would be perfect for that situation. Try the 'try/catch' around the ->send() call? Just catch \Exception, but maybe also \Error and \ErrorException. Do you know the error types that are set in php.ini? Maybe it's a parse error?

Comment: Check the php-fpm logs, this looks like OOM killer's doing or a segfault in a module.

Comment: @UnderDog when I do `php artisan tinker` and run `config('logging.emergency')` it shows `[ "path" => "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log", ]`. Do I have to do anything further to enable?

I tried a try-catch around `$r1->send()` and I was catching `\Throwable`. and logging. Doesn't seem to trigger, though.

Comment: Open that logging.php file and set it at least to 'emergency.log' or something, but I don't think anything ends up in there this time. Are you able to `var_dump` the $exception when you catch the \Throwable? It's an interesting challenge, even though it sucks it on a live environment

Comment: @soulseekah I'm also suspicious of a php-fpm problem. I've updated my post to explain the debugging I've done with respect to that, but I wonder if there are further steps I could be taking?

Comment: @UnderDog sorry if I wasnt' clear, but my `try-catch` with `\Throwable` actually isn't catching any exception; somehow PHP terminates without an exception (or in the case where I changed the echo statement it returns successfully from send and still ends up with 500).

Also, I checked and we have debug-level logging enabled. So we should be getting emergency-level logs (we do get laravel log statements from normal failures like an exception thrown during a request, so its not as if logging doesn't work at all).

Comment: @ChaseMedallion what's in `sendHeaders`?

Comment: @soulseekah that's a laravel built-in function that sets header values for the request.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was the `Link` header being generated by laravel's `AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets` middleware. The addition of a single new javascript module dependency made the list of prefetch modules overflow Apache's 8192-byte header size limit.

I've [filed an issue with Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/49214) to see if they can avoid this happening by default.

Until then, I'm replacing the built-in middleware with my own version that avoids making overly-long headers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait until this is fixed in apache2, or switch to nginx:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64919
- https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/http-response-header-size-limit-with-mod-proxy-fcgi