# Internal 500 error on magento site. Premature end of script headers

Tags: php, magento

Hi I have a magento site which now gives me an **internal 500 error** when loading the website.

Permissions were changed across the whole **/var/www** to a different user but it messed things up.

So reverted back to **www-data**. All other sites are fine except for the magento sites. I checked the log and it shows the following error continously:

```
[Thu Mar 13 13:59:31 2014] [warn] [client 66.249.67.68] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

[Thu Mar 13 13:59:31 2014] [error] [client 66.249.67.68] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

Any ideas how i can resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the file permissions as described in the wiki. https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 pear
chmod 550 mage #for magento 1.5+
```

Comment: Hi,Unfortunately did not work but i changed permissions for the suexec  on the apache server and the site was working. But now i get errors Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper. But im sure there is something else in magento i need to change in order for the site to work rather than tje securoty on suexec for apache?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to debug your HTTP headers for length. Apache could crash if you go over it's internal HTTP header limit of 8K.

More information on HTTP headers for all important web servers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623061/286238 by [David Schoonover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92629/david-schoonover)