# What is the maximum length of the OAuth token given by Azure active directory in bytes

Tags: azure

I am having a scenario where I have to store OAuth token in a secured store where maximum length allowed is 255 characters.So, I want to know the maximum length of OAuth token delivered by Azure. Is it less then 255?

Comment: are two talking about individual length of each claim? if yes, then it is correct that individual claim on JWT token have maximum length of 250 characters as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#azure-ad-b2c-configuration-limits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OAuth tokens returned by Azure AD are essentially base64 encoded JWT tokens and currently there's no maximum length defined (Ref: [What is the maximum size of JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033983/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-jwt-token)).

Having said that, in my experience they are definitely more than 255 characters. See one below for example:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1eFI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.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.UcAFjUnbmfqqbPcMt99sEs5nfXXJIyXKIeXZJz04Qyuz7BXco5LbVibMxmNisPGlL2qQYB0XFIuVyUk0PwiCuAIlj1f5flPLyW7K339urANTCyJn4KCAstq838BeY32rCPUIDfKc5fCbxoSBNkwhd3tXjIaV60BzFiK4a1scjge7BHJrqYsnC22CC88R39N77vIQTfGhNK83IaRdEIbmgr5-Wjy3yjRJ-qLQ6A5insNxTc-hgbe-PaxBhO8Rvu3xBCUfJTo77XXrHJKLx5tZVp2m28bs53wMThN0v8eVqaWn3bP1o_AYSxMJlb7EeIZ_wyzC3aPWRp_LNNSNgyp4xg