# 400 Bad Request if Authorization Bearer token used

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, jwt

I'm using PostMan to troubleshoot an odd 400 error with my Angular / NodeJS app.

I'm trying to GET `https://example.com/login.html` and the request has two headers:

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc...==` and `Accept: text/html`

This returns a `400 Bad Request` error (server: cloudflare-nginx)

*This works fine (returns `200`) if:*

- I access the file in my local environment on `http://localhost:5000/login.html` (no https factor?) -or-
- I remove `Authorization: Bearer` from the header

If I watch my NodeJS server logs, I don't even see the request come through. So `/login.html` doesn't even get hit, I assume because Express is rejecting it before my `app.use(logger('dev'));` picks it up.

UPDATE: I believe Cloudflare is kicking it back with 400 prior to the request ever reaching Heroku.

A few more points:

- I am using JWT to authenticate users, which is where the Bearer token comes from.
- If I access other endpoints, such as `/profile` with the Bearer token, it responds properly with the user profile from decoding the token.

My question is:

- Why would this request be a "Bad Request" when it works on other endpoints?
- Is there a way to catch this and do something with the request before it's returned as 400?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was related to my implementation of JWT. For some reason, one user continued to receive a token that caused these 400 errors, even though the token was verified as valid using JWT.io.

I made two significant changes that fixed the issue:

1. I was embedding the full user profile (long JSON) in the token payload. I reduced it to just their userid, both for performance reasons (far smaller size) and just in case something in the complex payload was causing the issue.
2. I switched from JWT-Simple to `jsonwebtoken` in my node implementation.

I'm just glad that worked. My next step was to switch from 'Authorization' to 'x-encoded-auth' or some other custom name.

Comment: any documentation from cloudflare on this?

Comment: i think im having some SSL issue that is breaking the authentication. When I access without SSL it is working - so hoping the size of the user profile isn't the problem

Comment: @Simon_Weaver have you tried switching to JWT-Simple?

Comment: Already spent enough time this weekend figuring out identityserver and refresh tokens and angular2. Hoping I can figure out the problem now it appears to be SSL related

Comment: I've been seeing this issue recently, with a Bearer token that was particularly big - about 3k.  I need to see if I can utilize your suggestions.  Thank you very much for posting your answer!

Comment: It turns out some colleagues have seen this problem before.  This was their suggestion on how to solve:
"Node express has certain limits by default on request payload size and exceeding these limits for certain users in your case and causing an issue. You can override these default limits in your node express API as below:

`this.express.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: ‘50mb’ }));`
`this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: ‘50mb’, extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));`
"

Answer (score 0):

@James, I don't have enough reputation to post a comment on your answer, but I thought it would be helpful to others struggling with this issue to state that your suggestion to reduce the complexity/size of the signed user indeed resulted in resolving similar issues I was experiencing. This was on my list of performance optimizations anyway - but it didn't occur to me that it could be a cause for error in this scenario - so you deserve the credit... thanks!

For readers - there are some useful links in this SO thread about max size for tokens: [What is the maximum size of JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033983/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-jwt-token)

And this is a tool I use to check the validity of a generated tokens... https://www.base64decode.org/

Hope this justifies the upgrade from comment to answer!