# How to Measure the Size of JWT?

Tags: jwt, token

How do you measure the size of a JWT token? It is a long string value.

I would like the token to be less than 7 kb.

(https://medium.com/dataseries/public-claims-and-how-to-validate-a-jwt-1d6c81823826)

([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033983/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-jwt-token#:~:text=As%20a%20JWT%20is%20included,of%20room%20for%20other%20headers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033983/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-jwt-token#:%7E:text=As%20a%20JWT%20is%20included,of%20room%20for%20other%20headers.))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JWT is just 3 `base64` strings, concatenated with `.` characters. So, unless you somehow force it into a wider character set, 1 character = 1 byte.

Total size will be a function of the signing algorithm in use, and the actual payload size. `base64` has 3:4 overhead. So, your JWT will always be raw payload size * 1.25, plus signature and header. I usually just think of it as 1.5x overhead, and if you come in smaller that's a bonus.

All that said 7kb is pretty huge for something meant to be passed in an HTTP header. I don't know what the hard limit is, but practically speaking I like to stay under 1kb, and ideally under a few hundred characters.

Comment: I still don't understand about how to measure the size of a token. Please take a look at this link (https://medium.com/dataseries/public-claims-and-how-to-validate-a-jwt-1d6c81823826) and you will find a  a long string value

Comment: It's just a string. 1 character = 1 byte, unless you're doing something weird like using utf16 or utf32 over HTTP

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @superstator in my case I've used [www.lettercount.com](https://lettercount.com) and there I pasted the Header + Payload + Verify Signature and total characters is below 300. Does that also means (by Google's 1kb = 1000 bytes) the size of my JWT is 0.3kB? I've read at [https://jwt.io/introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction) saying 8kB is the max limit which seems like they'd need over 8000 characters, I'm thinking what'd they write in there a poem lol? .. That's why I doubt if my calculations are right?

Comment: @Aleksandar yes, your math is fine. 8k is not an immutable limit, it's just a common maximum for any header on various HTTP servers. That limit can be smaller, or larger, but keeping tokens as small as possible is always the safest bet