# What is the maximum length of a token generated by jsonwebtoken npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm using the `jwt.sign()` method with an object (`{username: String}`) as the payload to create a refresh token. I want to then store the refresh token (in hex form) in a MySQL database and therefore want to know the maximum possible length of the token.

I understand that jsonwebtoken uses SHA256 by default, so I thought the generated token would be 64 characters as I'm converting it to hex, but it was above 100 characters and different lengths for different usernames.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit. Any json can be encoded and decoded back to a json. If there was a limit, decoding would be impossible

Comment: "*I understand that jsonwebtoken uses SHA256 by default,*" the whole of the token is not *hashed*. It's Base64 encoded and there are three sections of the token - header, payload, signature. The signature includes a hash to verify the token is complete.

Comment: The JWT is `header.payload.signature`. The _signature_ is the hash, which does have a max length (43 characters, 258 bits), but the _whole JWT_ is variable length (with a practical maximum of ~7kb per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/26033983/3001761).

Comment: *I'm converting it to hex,* - What's the benefit of converting a token that consists of Base64URL encoded strings to hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the base64 encoding does not mean any string will be encoded in 64 length of character.

There is not any maximum limit. Even the length of a JWT is not strictly defined by the JWT specification itself. The length of JWT can be vary depending on the size of your json header and payload.

Jwt consist of three parts

1. Header: base64url encoded
2. Payload: base64url encoded
3. Signature: The signature is the result of applying the specified algorithm to the encoded header and encoded payload with a secret key.

So the length can vary depending on the header, payload and the algorithms used to encode it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a limit, but you can manage the token's length by passing a limited amount of data when creating the JWT token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).