# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while writing JSON string to Printwriter in Struts

Tags: java, json, http-headers, httpresponse, struts-1

I am getting a `List` of rows from database and converting into `JSONstring` and writing it to `PrintWritter` to send output as JSON.

I was able to write some number of rows until now it is giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the line pointed in the below code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(subAreaCriteriaList);
response.setHeader("X-JSON", jsonString);

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write(jsonString);//exception at this line
writer.flush();
```

Here is my action method

```
public Object doGetSubAreasifExist(BaseActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        try {
            CurrentRoute route = new CurrentRoute();
            String areaID = request.getParameter("areaID");
            LoginService bbcService = (LoginService) Context.getInstance()
                                                            .getBean("LoginService");

            DetachedCriteria subAreaCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(CabArea.class);
            subAreaCriteria.add(Restrictions.ne(CabArea.PROP_ID, Long.parseLong(areaID)));

            List<CabArea> subAreaCriteriaList = bbcService.findAll(subAreaCriteria);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonString = gson.toJson(subAreaCriteriaList);
            response.setHeader("X-JSON", jsonString);

            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write(jsonString);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

here is my part of *strut-config xml*

```
<action path="/admin/cabsharing/getSubAreasifExist"
            type="com.ihexa.common.admin.cabsharing.action.CabsharingAction"
            name="actionForm">              
</action>
```

Here is my stacktrace

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.write(InternalOutputBuffer.java:701)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.sendStatus(InternalOutputBuffer.java:438)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1626)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:958)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:183)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.sendHeaders(Response.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.finishResponse(Response.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:317)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
```

Comment: If you are using struts2.x then you may use struts inbuilt support for JSON, refer [struts2 and json example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)

Comment: @VisruthCV i have pointed out the exception ouccrrring at which line number. Error is not about the response sending back but is raised inside method. And it has nothing to do with struts version .I am able send certain amount of data but when i exceed it gives me the error

Comment: it seems to be struts1.x.

Comment: Can you post the contents in `jsonString` (the one which generated this exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment added by you *I am able send certain amount of data but when i exceed it gives me the error*, it seems like the header size (in your case it is `response.setHeader("X-JSON", jsonString);`) exceeded the maximum limit (refer [Maximum on http header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) may be helpful) and the issue seems to be server specific.

If you are using Apache Tomcat then you can refer [maxHttpHeaderSize in Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) to modify *conf/server.xml*. Setting *maxHttpHeaderSize* in *server.xml* will fix your issue. Here is a [sample server.xml](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=a656/server.xml) file for *maxHttpHeaderSize* usage.

You also have to close `writer` object as follows :

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Comment: Actually it was not necessary to write in header for sending back json response. I have change the line response.setHeader("X-JSON", jsonString); to response.setHeader("X-JSON", "test"); Now its working fine . Thanx @Visruth CV