# Google Adwords CSP (content security policy) img-src

Tags: javascript, http, google-ads-api, content-security-policy

What domains/protocols in the `img-src` directive of the Content-Security-Policy header are required to allow Google AdWords conversion tracking?

From testing, when we call `google_trackConversion`, it looks like the browser creates an image with a src that follows a chain of 302 redirects between various domains...

```
www.googleadservices.com ->
googleads.g.doubleclick.net ->
www.google.com ->
www.google.co.uk
```

The final `.co.uk` looks suspicious to me. As we're testing from the UK, we're concerned that tracking called from other countries will redirect to other domains.

What is the complete list of domains that we need to open up in order for the tracking to work?

---

As requested in comments, an example path component of the first request is:

```
pagead/conversion/979383382/?random=1452934690748&cv=8&fst=1452934690748&num=1&fmt=3&label=jvoMCNP4umIQ1uiA0wM&guid=ON&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1033&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_his=18&u_tz=0&u_java=false&u_nplug=5&u_nmime=7&frm=0&url=https%3A//beta.captevate.com/payment%3Flevel%3Da00&async=1
```

and repeating the conversion a second time, the path component of the first request is

```
pagead/conversion/979383382/?random=1452934959209&cv=8&fst=1452934959209&num=1&fmt=3&label=jvoMCNP4umIQ1uiA0wM&guid=ON&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1033&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_his=26&u_tz=0&u_java=false&u_nplug=5&u_nmime=7&frm=0&url=https%3A//beta.captevate.com/payment%3Flevel%3Da00&async=1
```

---

I used a free VPN service to connect from a couple of countries (Netherlands and Singapore), and the last redirect doesn't occur: the final request to `www.google.com` is a 200. However, I obviously haven't tried connected from *every* country, so my original question stands.

Comment: Would you mind posting the path component of the original tracking image? Or does Google change that in an unpredictable way, potentially along with the domain?

Comment: Have you tried to use some kind of VPN or proxy to get an foreign ip and check your suspicion? Maybe you will be redirected to the .co.uk domain anyway.

Comment: @sgammon I have added the path component of the original request

Comment: @Phonolog Yes, and added details to the question.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies but I still can't find a good solution to this problem.
Also, we need to allow www and other domains.
Does it mean we must put all google domains twice:
google.be and *.google.be or is there a shorter version that will not open door to security risk?
is there any risk of some browser not allowing that long headers, or is only only the WebServer that will limit the length?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't many ways around this. Resources require either whitelisting (in the case of remote resources, like this one) or inlining tricks (i.e. `nonce` or `sha256-...`) when CSP is active. At the end of the day, though, CSP can probably still make your site safer and protect most resources.

Depending on what you are trying to do, though, you may still be able to achieve your goal.

**Here are some options:**

1. **Whitelist all images.**

   Of course, you could simply place a `"*"` in your `img-src` directive, but I imagine you already know that and are choosing not to because it defeats CSP's protection for images.
2. **Load the image via alternate means.**

   If all you are after is specifically locking down images, and, say, don't care so much about `XMLHttpRequest`, you could load the pixel via `POST` or even via a `<script>` tag with a custom `type` (using the [AdWords image tag](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/image/) tracking method). This takes advantage of the fact that Google only needs the browser to complete the HTTP request/response (and redirect) cycle for analytics purposes, and you don't really care about parsing or executing the resulting content, which is a 1x1 transparent pixel anyways. This allows you to lock down your `img-src` directive (if that is indeed your goal) while still allowing whatever domain Google would like to use for redirects.

   I know this only moves your problem, but it's useful if your main threat is malicious images.
3. **Place all Google domains in your `img-src`.**

   As suggested below. Header lengths *will* be a problem (even if the specs say you're fine, implementors are not always so generous), and more importantly, you may encounter spurious failures as Google changes their list of domains, which is certainly not a public or easily noticeable action (besides your ad conversions not coming through!). Since I imagine your job *isn't* to update that list constantly, you probably don't want to go with this option.
4. **Report failures for a few months and then roll with it.**

   Because CSP supports reporting URIs and the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` variant, you can roll it out in report-only mode and wait for reports to come in. If you already have good data about your userbase (and it doesn't change much), this can be a good option - once you see those reports stabilize on a list of domains, seal it in a regular CSP header. Optionally, you can place a reporting URI on the final header to catch any additional failures. The downside of this strategy, of course, is that you don't get protection while in report-only mode, and when you switch to enforcing it, failures cause lost conversion data and you're playing catch up.
5. **Static pixel with reverse proxy**

   Okay. Well, with the above options not being so great (I admit it), it's time to think outside the box. The problem here is that HTTP optimization techniques applied by Google (sharding/geo-pinning domains) are at odds with good security practice (i.e. CSP). The root cause of the domain ambiguity is the client's geographic location, so why not pin it yourself?

Assuming you have advanced control of your own HTTP server, you could use the static pixel approach for tracking and proxy the request yourself, like so:

```
User ---> GET http://your-page/

User <--- <html>...
          pixel: http://your-page/pixel?some=params

User ---> http://your-page/pixel?some=params
          ---> fetch http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/12345/?some=params
          <--- redirect to http://google.com, or http://google.co.uk
User <--- return redirect
```

Using a [static pixel](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/image/) (like approach #2) and putting your proxy, say, in the US or UK should ensure that the source IP is geographically pinned there, and Google's anycast frontend should route you to a stable endpoint. Placing a proxy in between the user and Google also gives you a chance to force-rewrite the redirect if you want to.

To simplify proxy setup (and add some performance spice), you could opt for something like [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) with [Origin Shielding](https://docs.fastly.com/guides/about-fastly-services/about-fastlys-origin-shielding-features) instead of building it yourself. If you add the DoubleClick backend and proxy from there, you can pin the originating requests from the CDN to come only from a certain geographic region. Either way, your user should see a stable set of redirects, and you can trim down that list of Google domains to just `img-src 'self' *.google.com *.doubleclick.net *.googleadservices.net`.

*Edit:* It is also worth noting that Fastly (and a [growing list of other CDN providers](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/cdn-interconnect#providers)) [peer directly with Google Cloud](https://www.fastly.com/blog/new-global-interconnects-between-fastly-google-cloud-platform) at a few of their Points-of-Presence, offering an optimized path into Google's networks for your proxied traffic.

Comment: I'd avoid option 2. You'd need to relax your `connect-src` or `form-src` directives, and the implications of those are much greater than a relaxed `img-src` directive.

Comment: in general you're probably right, @Polynomial, but, on a children's site, perhaps images would be your main concern? who knows what his use case is. my goal is only to help :)

Answer (score 14):

What are you trying to achieve by locking down your img-src?

CSP is a great security option but most issues are with javascript (which can cause all sorts of issues), css (which can be used to hide or overly elements with injected content) or framing options (which can be used for click-jacking by similarly overlying content). Images are a much smaller risk IMHO.

There are few security risks that I can think of with loading images, which boil down to:

1. Tracking and the privacy implications of that. Though you are already using Google Adwords which tracks so much. And those that care about this typically block it in their browser.
2. Loading of insecure content (I presume you are using HTTPS exclusively or this whole conversation is a bit pointless?). This can be remediated with a more loose CSP policy of just https for img-src.
3. Loading an image and subsequently overlying part of your website with that rogue image. But that requires javascript and/or CSS injection too - which should be locked down in CSP.

Ultimately unless you have a XSS vulnerability people shouldn't be able to easily load images into your pages. And even if they could I think the risks are small.

So, I would be tempted to just have a "img-src 'self' https:;" rather than try any of the other work arounds the others have suggested - all of which have downsides and are not very future proof.

Ultimately if you are that concerned about security of your site that locking down images is a high priority I would question whether you should be running *Google Adwords*.

However if there is a specific threat you are trying to protect against, while at the same time still allowing *Adwords*, then provide details of that and there may be other ways around it. At the moment you've asked for a solution to particular problem without necessarily explaining the actual underlying problem which may have solutions other than the one you are asking about.

Comment: I just want to mention that this answer misses the security risk. 

With an open image-src an attacker can extract things like passwords, api-keys, credit card info etc etc. 

So how that become an issue? Beside the XSS vulnerability the answer mentions it could also happen if a dependency you use goes malicious.

Comment: To clarify @MikaelEliasson 's comment if people are wondering how being able to load an image would help an attacker achieve that: It's not about the ability to load images, it's about the ability for malicious code to make a network request to an arbitrary domain. If your code running in the user's browser captured their password, you still have to get that data off their computer to use it. If the CSP allows '*' for img-src, then the attacker can just try to load an image with the url: "attackers-domain/users-password-here.png", and have the server at that domain save those requests.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Wikipedia's [List of Google domains](https://en.wikipedia-on-ipfs.org/wiki/List_of_Google_domains.html). There are many domains unrelated to Google Adwords, but I don't think allowing domains like `youtube.com` could cause problems.

Currently the list is:

```
google.com
google.ac
google.ad
google.ae
google.com.af
google.com.ag
google.com.ai
google.al
google.am
google.co.ao
google.com.ar
google.as
google.at
google.com.au
google.az
google.ba
google.com.bd
google.be
google.bf
google.bg
google.com.bh
google.bi
google.bj
google.com.bn
google.com.bo
google.com.br
google.bs
google.bt
google.co.bw
google.by
google.com.bz
google.ca
google.com.kh
google.cc
google.cd
google.cf
google.cat
google.cg
google.ch
google.ci
google.co.ck
google.cl
google.cm
google.cn
g.cn
google.com.co
google.co.cr
google.com.cu
google.cv
google.com.cy
google.cz
google.de
google.dj
google.dk
google.dm
google.com.do
google.dz
google.com.ec
google.ee
google.com.eg
google.es
google.com.et
google.fi
google.com.fj
google.fm
google.fr
google.ga
google.ge
google.gf
google.gg
google.com.gh
google.com.gi
google.gl
google.gm
google.gp
google.gr
google.com.gt
google.gy
google.com.hk
google.hn
google.hr
google.ht
google.hu
google.co.id
google.iq
google.ie
google.co.il
google.im
google.co.in
google.io
google.is
google.it
google.je
google.com.jm
google.jo
google.co.jp
google.co.ke
google.ki
google.kg
google.co.kr
google.com.kw
google.kz
google.la
google.com.lb
google.com.lc
google.li
google.lk
google.co.ls
google.lt
google.lu
google.lv
google.com.ly
google.co.ma
google.md
google.me
google.mg
google.mk
google.ml
google.com.mm
google.mn
google.ms
google.com.mt
google.mu
google.mv
google.mw
google.com.mx
google.com.my
google.co.mz
google.com.na
google.ne
google.com.nf
google.com.ng
google.com.ni
google.nl
google.no
google.com.np
google.nr
google.nu
google.co.nz
google.com.om
google.com.pk
google.com.pa
google.com.pe
google.com.ph
google.pl
google.com.pg
google.pn
google.co.pn
google.com.pr
google.ps
google.pt
google.com.py
google.com.qa
google.ro
google.rs
google.ru
google.rw
google.com.sa
google.com.sb
google.sc
google.se
google.com.sg
google.sh
google.si
google.sk
google.com.sl
google.sn
google.sm
google.so
google.st
google.sr
google.com.sv
google.td
google.tg
google.co.th
google.com.tj
google.tk
google.tl
google.tm
google.to
google.tn
google.com.tr
google.tt
google.com.tw
google.co.tz
google.com.ua
google.co.ug
google.co.uk
google.com
google.com.uy
google.co.uz
google.com.vc
google.co.ve
google.vg
google.co.vi
google.com.vn
google.vu
google.ws
google.co.za
google.co.zm
google.co.zw
admob.com
adsense.com
adwords.com
android.com
blogger.com
blogspot.com
chromium.org
chrome.com
chromebook.com
cobrasearch.com
googlemember.com
googlemembers.com
com.google
feedburner.com
doubleclick.com
igoogle.com
foofle.com
froogle.com
googleanalytics.com
google-analytics.com
googlecode.com
googlesource.com
googledrive.com
googlearth.com
googleearth.com
googlemaps.com
googlepagecreator.com
googlescholar.com
gmail.com
googlemail.com
keyhole.com
madewithcode.com
panoramio.com
picasa.com
sketchup.com
urchin.com
waze.com
youtube.com
youtu.be
yt.be
ytimg.com
youtubeeducation.com
youtube-nocookie.com
like.com
google.org
google.net
466453.com
gooogle.com
gogle.com
ggoogle.com
gogole.com
goolge.com
googel.com
duck.com
googlee.com
googil.com
googlr.com
googl.com
gmodules.com
googleadservices.com
googleapps.com
googleapis.com
goo.gl
googlebot.com
googlecommerce.com
googlesyndication.com
g.co
whatbrowser.org
localhost.com
withgoogle.com
ggpht.com
youtubegaming.com
```

However, if you want to be sure if that's really all domains, you should ask Google directly.

Comment: Is there a limit to the CSP header length that doing this would exceed?

Comment: @MichalCharemza There aren't any limits to HTTP headers length, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values

Comment: it doesn't cover tons of domains like gstatic.com

Comment: Google has a page at https://www.google.com/supported_domains which may be useful for keeping up to date on this

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no clean workaround, it only accepts wildcards `*` on the left of the domain.

You can disable this feature on GTM or Universal Analytics but if you do use Google Adds it requires this to calculate the segments to target your add, otherwise your adds will be very expensive (and not targeted)

So: you can check all valid google domains here  https://www.google.com/supported_domains

And add them  on the white list on `img-src` and `connect-src` on your CSP Policy, had cross your fingers that goggle will not add more (you could monitor this url for changes with any of thee services that does this)

This nightmare ends in mid 2023 when they will deprecate Universal Analytics, GA4 does not use this.

Not sure if you guys are using anything to report the CSP failures, we discovered this service https://report-uri.com/  the free tier gives a reasonable endpoint to report on failures, once we went live we burned our quota in 2 days thought... but it did help to find holes in our CSP.

It did crash our server, we had to increase the HTTP header size once we put twice all google domains