# How to configure CSP for all all Google domains (i.e. .com, .de, .fr, etc)

Tags: http, https, http-headers, content-security-policy

I am whitelisting domains for CSP headers. Is there any recommendation for whitelisting a big list of domain, all belonging to the same company e.g. `google.de`, `google.fr`, etc.

If I understand correctly, `*.mydomain.com` means both subdomains of `mydomain.com` and also `mydomain.com` itself. For security itself, it doesn't make sense to allow *any* top level domain of `google.<tld>`, yet it would be very convenient to have a shorthand way to list all `google.<tld>` that I can find.

Is there a shorter / better alternative to maintaining a list of all possible `google.*`?

Comment: You might be interested in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361383/google-adwords-csp-content-security-policy-img-src/

Answer (score 6):

At least for now, a seemingly reliable list would be: https://www.google.com/supported_domains