# How to get the size of http request/response header using Netty?

Tags: java, http, http-headers, netty

In my use case I would like to get the size of the http header in bytes using [Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty). I went through the source code of Netty. By default the header size is 8KiB [8192 bytes]. It ignores the remaining headers ( [decoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/83c349ffa94d3992c4ee511d3625afc0c97c12bb/codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/rtsp/RtspDecoder.java) ). But Netty does not provide a function to get the current header size.

Is there a function to get the size of the header using Netty? If not, what is the best way get the header size from the http request? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You've linked a RTSP decoder, not a HTTP decoder. But in any case this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP header block consists of a variable number of lines of variable length, and the block is terminated by a blank line. It doesn't have a predefined size, or a size that is available via any API I am aware of.