# ajax falied(net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG)

Tags: javascript, ajax

My problem is `ajax(get) falied`. console show `'net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG'`

I aleady see reason of ajax error that is **'set-cookie'** problem.
but I don't have any information that, what is it?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: Is this helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

Comment: My code is just xhr.onload!! but.. i have met this problem! ㅜㅜ how can i solve it? is this client or server-side problem??

Comment: David, did you ever get an answer? Could you share it?