# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, large HTTP headers

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x, spring-oauth2

I'm using 
`org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient`
to send a request. Whenever the size of one of the headers is large (around `103452` bytes), I get a:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

The connection is probably not being reset by the server, since other clients from other java apps (probably using a spring OAUTH/REST client) appear to be able to use the service while sending similarly large headers.

Even though the proper fix is to avoid the need to send such a large header in the first place, is there a configuration of `org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient` that will prevent it from crashing on large headers?

The client is built with:

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build()
```

Comment: How sure are you the server isn't rejecting the request?  The HTTP spec doesn't impose a limit, and I don't believe the Apache client imposes one in it's default configuration.  However, web servers do... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values for some details.  Note that the limits the web servers impose are for combined size of all headers, not a single header.

Comment: good point. I will confirm

Comment: Could you please add your comment as an answer? I tried sending the request to a local server: `sudo nc -l 80`. The request with a 100Kb header was sent perfectly fine by the apache http client. At the same time, I tried sending the same request to the real server via a `curl` client, and I got a `curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted`. So even the proxy might be rejecting such a large header size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How sure are you the server isn't rejecting the request?

The HTTP spec doesn't impose a limit, and I don't believe the Apache client imposes one in it's default configuration.

However, web servers do... See [Maximum on http header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) for some details. Note that the limits the web servers impose are for combined size of all headers, not a single header.

Comment: you're right. it appears that the server was indeed rejecting the request, and that other successful clients were not sending large headers. this was an issue with oauth token explosion: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/opaque-access-tokens-cloud-foundry/ which was fixed by limiting the requested scopes