# Jetty server closes the stream generating an 500 error

Tags: http-headers, jetty, response-headers

When constructing a http response using `jetty-9.4.6` I get the following exception. In my particular case I'm constructing the message from camel but this doesn't impact the behavior.

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not write to XMLStreamWriter.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxOutEndingInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:278)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:247)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Closed
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1421)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeEndDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxOutEndingInterceptor.java:56)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:476)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination$JettyOutputStream.write(JettyHTTPDestination.java:322)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.close(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1419)
    ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If the headers are beyond a certain size the exception is thrown. See [Maximum on http header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) .

The exception doesn't suggest the reason for closing.