# What's the use of JWT in Rails + React app for Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, jwt

I don't understand the use of JWT token..
Can anyone explain it to me ?
Because currently i'm working on an app (rails + react), and I want to use devise + jwt for authentification and React for frontend.

Actually, I understood that :

1/ If a user want to login: he completes the form, React get Data from form and make a post request of these infos to Rails API.

2/ Rails API get theses infos check in the db if infos match with a registered user, if it is then Rails API will create a JWT token and will send this token to React.
User is now logged in because Rails API found a matched user.

3/ React receive the JWT token. ( ?? what the usage of this token ?? )

thanks

Comment: The token is used for all successive API calls, passing it in the HTTP Authorization header. Server side will validate the token every time before allowing the API request through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My response is not specific to `Rails`/`React`, but rather to all web technologies using JWT tokens:

What you said is correct. From point 3 forward, all the requests made from React to the Rails backend will have to contain the header `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

When Rails sees that header, it is able to:

- checks the token is valid, by checking its signature
- decode it and extract any info stored in it.

Remember that JWT tokens can contain any info the backend wants to store in it. And the client **is not able to tamper it**, because it is signed cryptographically and it would invalidate its signature.

The above properties (the fact you can store anything in it, that the frontend sends it with every request and that nobody can tamper it) help any web application being able to:

- have a [**shared nothing architecture**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared-nothing_architecture) - because the session is stored completely on the UI, so any backend worker/machine can handle any request
- store [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623061/459233) in the session than if they'd use [signed cookies](https://www.quora.com/What-Is-The-Maximum-Size-Of-Cookie-In-A-Web-Browser) for sessions.

Comment: Okay soo the best way to send data from my backend to my front or front to backend is to send a JWT token ?

Comment: only for the session related things like user info and user roles. For the other info, use `AJAX` or websockets.

Comment: Can I use Axios instead of AJAX?

Comment: yeah, axios makes the ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

Since you are return api . And react is consuming it.
Jwt help to return data you might need to persist in your frontend in react  tho. Data like user name or email.
Example : making the header of your website show a user is logged in.

Comment: Jwt  store in user browser local storage . Then you can call it from there that if data username in jwt exist then perform soooooo in the frontend . In a user aspect it does not need to ask db to validate user again  but can do that through jwt

Comment: If you still dont get     https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0

Comment: Hi hazmat, just as a heads up: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57918212/edit) answers (and questions) to add information. This has the advantages of being clearer to see for readers, as comments get out of order quite quickly and also sometimes get deleted automaticall

Answer (score 0):

Since you are return api . And react is consuming it.
Jwt help to return data you might need to persist in your frontend in react  tho. Data like user name or email.
Example : making the header of your website show a user is logged in.
The main aim of jwt in frontend is basically auth.
Apart .
If you are using a monolith app u deal with session for user 
In react case jwt stands in  as the session

Answer (score 0):

The main aim of jwt in frontend is basically auth or other. 
Apart . If you are using a monolith app remeber  u deal with session for user In react case jwt stands in as the session