# Request Header or Cookie Too Large but we're well within limits

Tags: nginx, cookies

We have started adding some user details to our cookies for other subdomains to access. This works great, however when a user goes to domain.com, the public website, that also adds more cookies, then coming back to some of the apps we get the `400 error Request Header or Cookie Too Large`

I've googled and seen we can set nginx to allow a higher threshold, even one of our .Net servers gave us a similar error.

Looking at the cookies in Chrome dev toolbar, nothing looks like we exceed the limits documented. This is where I think I'm missing something. Is nginx purposefully configured too low? Or are these sizes mispresented?

> Practical user agent implementations have limits on the number and
> size of cookies that they can store.  General-use user agents SHOULD
> provide each of the following minimum capabilities:
>
> o  At least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the sum of the
> length of the cookie's name, value, and attributes).
>
> o  At least 50 cookies per domain.
>
> o  At least 3000 cookies total.
>
> Servers SHOULD use as few and as small cookies as possible to avoid
> reaching these implementation limits and to minimize network
> bandwidth due to the Cookie header being included in every request.
>
> Servers SHOULD gracefully degrade if the user agent fails to return
> one or more cookies in the Cookie header because the user agent might
> evict any cookie at any time on orders from the user.

ref: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt

Our largest cookie is 2842 bytes, well under the 4096 limit. We have 30 cookies total, again under the 50 limit

[image]

If I delete about 1024bytes worth of cookies, it works. But I still have the top 3 largest there...

Answer (score 7):

You could reach another possible limit, a whole HTTP request header size (the `Cookie` header for your case), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values) SO thread for more details. For nginx web server it's value is controlled by the [`large_client_header_buffers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#large_client_header_buffers) directive and by default is equal to 4 buffers of 8K bytes. Try to increase it for example to

```
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
```