# HTTP: max length of etag

Tags: http, protocols, network-protocols, etag

Does the HTTP protocol specify a max length for the ETag?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[No](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19).

> #### 14.19 ETag
>
> The ETag response-header field provides the current value of the entity tag for the requested variant. The headers used with entity tags are described in sections [14.24](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24), [14.26](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) and [14.44](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44). The entity tag MAY be used for comparison with other entities from the same resource (see section [13.3.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3)).
>
> ```
>     ETag = "ETag" ":" entity-tag
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>     ETag: "xyzzy"
>     ETag: W/"xyzzy"
>     ETag: ""
> ```

Answer (score 13):

No, an [*entity-tag*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.11) is a [*quoted-string*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-2.2) with an optional weak indicator prefix and can be of any length in theory.

In practice, the length of a header field is limited, both by user agents and [web servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6160643/53114). The maximum viable length of the entire header field should be somewhere at 8 KiB.