# Determining maximum length of ETag that can be returned by Google People API

Tags: etag, google-people-api

Is there a definition of the length of the `etag` returned by the Google People API?

We store the `etag` returned and we recently started receiving `etag` values greater than the length of the database column that we had allocated. We modified the table to accommodate these new larger `etag`s but it raised the question of what to make the maximum size of the column.

I am wondering if there is any documentation where Google define the length of the `etag` field or explain the mechanism they use to generate it?

On a related note, is there anywhere that would have forewarned us about this change? I've browsed the People API documentation and searched for release notes, but I do not see any mention of this changing.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question `what to make the maximum size of the column`, there's really no way you can determine it, as an ETag can be of any length in theory so it would be best if you have a way to not set/limit the length. The method by which ETag values are generated is not specified. Typically, the ETag value is a hash of the content, a hash of the last modification timestamp, or just a revision number.

Refer to other links below for more information:

- [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag#directives)
- [HTTP: max length of etag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740814/http-max-length-of-etag)

Comment: Thanks @Dan F. I was pretty sure that was the case, but its good to have confirmation. I know in general the HTTP spec doesn't specify, but I wondered if maybe Google had shared how they were doing it for this API, but I was just unable to find it in the docs.

Comment: @Rikki For more specific details which cannot be found in any documentation, I suggest you raise an issue/concern here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues