# No Fedauth cookie are sent back as SAML token after reaching STS seems to miss XML tags. Happens only on Firefox

Tags: wif, ws-federation

I am scratching my head over a peculiar problem that seems to work on IE and Chrome.

We have a custom passive STS which serves a RP. All is well till i authenticate via my custom authentication service and then STS returns token which i can see in my temp folder. The POST operation which then sends the SAML 1.0 token hangs and silently dies instead of getting back the FedAuth cookie which would normally redirect me the RP

Note : RP and IP are hosted on web server that is behind a reverse proxy server (Nginx). Reverse proxy is hosted over SSL and all traffic to and fro proxy server and webserver is non SSL

The following get logged on the webserver

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 12/11/2013 5:16:33 PM 
Event time (UTC): 12/11/2013 5:16:33 PM 
Event ID: eef80ad2bffe425780dd46e5f28c0306 
Event sequence: 2 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 


Exception information: 
Exception type: XmlException 
Exception message: **Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed:   RequestedUnattachedReference, RequestSecurityTokenResponse,** RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection. Line 1, position 5852.

at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowUnexpectedEndOfFile(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetByteHard()
at System.Xml.XmlBufferReader.GetByte()
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.ReadStartElement()
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadEndElement()
at   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.ReadRSTRXml(XmlReader reader, RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr, WSTrustSerializationContext context, WSTrustConstantsAdapter trustConstants)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.ReadXmlElement(XmlReader reader, RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr, WSTrustSerializationContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustSerializationHelper.CreateResponse(XmlReader reader, WSTrustSerializationContext context, WSTrustResponseSerializer responseSerializer, WSTrustConstantsAdapter trustConstants)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrust13ResponseSerializer.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, WSTrustSerializationContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationSerializer.CreateResponse(WSFederationMessage message, WSTrustSerializationContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage message, WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage message)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetXmlTokenFromMessage(SignInResponseMessage message, WSFederationSerializer federationSerializer)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityToken(SignInResponseMessage message)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetSecurityToken(HttpRequest request)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignInWithResponseMessage(HttpRequest request)
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I dont understand why just for FF i get this problem. Is there a limitation on the size of the content that is sent in the header for FF?

Another question is : I have installed two different certificates one at proxy server (SSL)and one at webserver(STS) to signing the token. Can i use the same certificate? Should i?

Answer (score 0):

According to the top voted answer on the question [Can HTTP headers be too big for a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3436155/1330152), Firefox does have the lowest individual header-size (or at least did back in FF3.6). The accepted answer may help you though as you've mentioned you're behind a proxy.