# Managing Permissions with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-ad-b2c, claims

I want to use azure active directory B2C in my application.
I will have a lot of permissions like for example a certain user is allowed to read a table/write to the table etc. This could be hundreds of permissions if not thousands if the applications gets bigger. 
Should I use claims for this or would it be better to store this in a database?

Is there a limit on the amount of claims? Are there downsides of using too many claims (like Kerberos token bloat in active directory on premise)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is a limit to the amount of claims you can send.** Claims are sent in the token which is included in the request header. Both browsers and web servers have a max header size.

- For browser limits see: [Can HTTP headers be too big for browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326210/can-http-headers-be-too-big-for-browsers)
- For web server limits see:  [Maximum on http header values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values)

Also, since you need to include the token in every authenticated API call, **you'd be bloating every request adding unnecessary latency to your application**.

> Note: This is not specific to Azure AD B2C.