# Is Chrome failing when sending a large http header?

Tags: rest, google-chrome, http, http-headers, jwt

I have been troubleshooting an error on my web app and have concluded that Chrome is failing to handle my http request when my headers get too large.

#### Why are my headers large?

I am using a JWT authorization scheme that includes permissions in the JWT token.  With my admin account that token is growing as I have permissions for each tenant.  The JWT is currently around 5200 characters.

#### Why do I blame chrome?

I have tested the identical request in several environments:

- Swagger: fails with `TypeError: Failed to fetch`[image]
- Postman Chrome Extension: fails with `Could not get any response`[image]
- Postman Native App: Succeeds
- Python script using requests: Succeeds
- curl: Succeeds

For each test I have the same headers, url, and body (none because it is a GET).

#### Notes

- While researching this, I came across [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326210/can-http-headers-be-too-big-for-browsers) which suggests that Chrome is limited to 250KB headers.  Mine are under 6k.
- If I use a smaller Authorization header, then Swagger and the Postman Chrome Extension both succeed.

#### Bottom line:

1. Can we confirm my conclusion that Chrome is having trouble with the larger header?
2. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

My line of thoughts:
Chrome fails because it uses HTTP2
Postman native uses http1 that's why it works.
Curl fails for me (and works if using --http1.1)

I'm still investigating, but this seems a server-side issue about maximum header size. For example **http2_max_header_size**  config (in old nginx). Nowadays it's **large_client_header_buffers** , or similar config in kubernetes, load balancers etc.