# Is there a maximum length for a HTTP BASIC authentication username?

Tags: http-authentication

Is there a maximum length for a username or password which is sent to a web application through HTTP BASIC authentication? I looked through RFC2617 and couldn't find anything obvious, but was curious and wanted to make sure.

(This is all being done over SSL, so don't worry about security for my sake.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no spec-enforced limit on the auth token. However you may run into practical server-specific limits on HTTP headers in general, as [outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1097651/18936).

Comment: You may run into **client-side limitations** too. For example **proxytunnel** only allows passwords up to 24 characters in length.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html#restrictions there is a **limit of 255 characters** for the username (and the username may not contain : ).

On Windows there is additionally a limit of 255 characters for the password - if the password is longer it will be truncated.

Comment: The document linked is relevant to the behavior of a utility program bundled with Apache httpd, but not to Apache httpd itself, let alone general protocol limitations.

Comment: This is a good addition to accepted answer. Giving examples of how _tools_ limit username length.