# HTTP authentication header character limit for basic authentication?

Tags: php, apache, http, rest, authentication

I've researched that there is an overall HTTP request size limit, and read this is normally a restriction set by Apache. But considering there's a bunch of other headers I could send through, that I'm not, I highly doubt I'm reaching the overall request size limit.

All I'm doing, is HTTP Basic authentication for a REST API, sending an API Key and API Secret, which are both 30 characters in length. And this seems to just fall over and fail. Nothing happens.

However, if I shorten the API Key and API Secret to 28 characters each, it works.

I find it hard to believe, that for something like authentication, there is a hard limit of 28 characters for the "username" and "password"?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a maximum length for a HTTP BASIC authentication username?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027825/is-there-a-maximum-length-for-a-http-basic-authentication-username).

Comment: Or, if you think the duplicate doesn't answer your question, answer the following: _"And this seems to just fall over and fail."_ - how? A 4xx response status? Does anything get logged? What PHP application are you talking to? What happens when you do a request to a PHP script that just `var_dump()`s the request header?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question and it doesn't answer my question. But you nailed exactly where the difference is. Nothing happens. I var_dump() the request header, and I get nothing. If I make the username and password shorter, it seems to execute. It's like it's not even trying with a username and password that's "too long". I'm using RESTClient for Firefox to test, I'm going to try curl or another plugin and see if the problem isn't with the plugin.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add, there seems to be no errors in the logs too. I must be missing something and being stupid.

Comment: Does this happen on multiple servers? Do you have some (exotic) Apache or PHP security modules / plugins running?

Comment: I was running WAMP; but it seems the issue was something else. It turns out, it WAS the plugin / extension. Do not use RESTClient for Firefox apparently. I used POSTMAN for Google Chrome, and that worked splendidly. Even with the 30 character API Keys and API Secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue I was experiencing was due to the plugin / extension I was using with Mozilla Firefox, named RESTClient; which I was using to test my REST API.

I switched to Google Chrome, and gave the POSTMAN plugin / extension a try, and my 30 character API Key and API Secret worked splendidly. With RESTClient, the requests didn't even try to execute. No responses, nothing.

DON'T USE RESTClient. I will try and find a suitable alternative for Firefox. However, this leads me to believe that doing a proper curl request would probably be the best ground truth for testing your PHP REST API.