# send image to server in multipart iphone

Tags: iphone, image

I want to send an image to the server as a multipart data.

The data must be concated at the header part and not at the body part
and the Content-Disposition: part must be left blank.

Any code is really appreaciated.
Thanks in advance

For example

```
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

I want to append the data in the content type. How it can be done like for boundary there is boundary=%@ so for concating the data what keyword mus be used? *_*=%@.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how TTURLRequest does it here:

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#paiB7gGbH1E/trunk/Projects/three20/src/TTURLRequest.m&q=TTURLRequest.m%20multipart&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Or how ASIHTTPRequest does it here:

http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#puVSP9AmSPI/Classes/ASIFormDataRequest.m&q=ASIHTTPRequest.m%20multipart&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc

Better yet, use one of those two libraries to handle the multipart post for you.

Comment: Thanks esilver.. In both the case the image data is concatenated in the body part.. While I want to append it to header part.. Please let me knw hw it would be possible

Comment: Uhh, I don't think that is a good idea, aren't there size limitations to how big a header can be? Read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit

Comment: Otherwise you could use this function from TTURLRequest.m and base64 encode your image into a string I guess: 

- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field {
  if (!_headers) {
    _headers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  [_headers setObject:value forKey:field];
}