# Is there a size limit when using the "headers" property of the jQuery.ajax method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, size, limit

Is there a size limit when using the "headers" property of the jQuery.ajax method?

i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'submit.php',
    headers: { 'CUSTOM_DATA': someBigString },// Is there a limit for "someBigString"?
    success: function( returnData ){

        returnTestData = returnData;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP protocol doesn't define any limit for HTTP headers. There might be [limits on your web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit) though.