# What is the maximum size/length for custom response header?

Tags: asp.net, http, header, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a couple of custom response headers to be returned from ASP.Net web api actions, and I need to know if there's a hard or practical size limit that I should be concerned with?

Comment: Are you going to self-host a web api or are you deploying on IIS? For the latter the IIS will be limiting. See also this previous SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097651/is-there-a-practical-http-header-length-limit

Comment: Seems IIS self-host uses Http.sys internally which means you can look at the MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes in the Http.sys registry settings (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129)